# Angular Prime Ng Export Compo

Tags: angular, angularjs, primeng, export-to-pdf, primeng-datatable

Angular Primeng defines the "Export" structure. This explanation: for converting data in my existing datatable to pdf and excel format and downloading to my computer.
There is a very successful download for Excel, but different characters were appearing when downloading in pdf format. So the format did not download properly. That's why it didn't download the format properly.
Can you help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiVyG.png)--> that's what it had to be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJIPO.png) --> This is what I did

Comment: Please include the version of Angular and PrimeNG that you are using. If your angular version is 2.0 or greater, then you should remove the `angularjs` tag.

Comment: Angular CLI: 16.1.8                                                                                                                  PrimenNG: v16.2.0